# add intern in employees table

Tags: database, oracle, database-design, ddl

I have an employees table and the ERD looks like this

[image]

I want to add more requirements. I want to add if the employees are seasonal or fulltime. I thought of adding an extra column on the duration table where I can track if employees are seasonal or fulltime. If seasonal, then some of the seasonal employees might be interns from colleges. For them, I want to add another table to track the university they are enrolled in. is this approach okay or should I create different table for status of employees?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are only two options available, i.e. whether an employee is

- full time or
- seasonal

then the simplest option is to add a "checkbox" column, e.g.

```
alter table employees add cb_seasonal number(1) default 0 not null;
```

which will be set to `0` (i.e. everyone is NOT seasonal which means that everyone IS full time employed). When someone switches to a seasonal status, you'd just "check" it by updating the row and setting the column value to `1`.

However, if there were more statuses, then it would be better to use additional table. You'd still have to alter the `employees` table and add a foreign key constraint to that "additional" table you created.

Comment: I did something like that. I added an extra column in the table wich check constraint "seasonal" or "fulltime". The problem for me is that some seasonal employees might be interns. If so, an intern's college should be recorded as well. Should I deal with new one to one relation table?

Comment: Yes, I'd say so (unless you already have table of colleges). There would be a foreign key constraint pointing to the newly created table.